# Can't resize /dev/sda1 partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I want to resize my `/dev/sda1` partition and I'm using GParted. This is my partition table:

[image: partition table]

When I tried to reize the `/dev/sda1` partition, I was unable to enlarge it to anything bigger than 7679 MB even though I have 11.53 GB in unallocated space:

[image: resize]

I don't know what to do now but I'd appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extended partition `/dev/sda2` which contains unallocated space, delete the partition first and then extend the 1st partition `/dev/sda1`

Comment: you have only upvoted but not accepted , click the grey ☑ under the "1" at the left of the text, which means "I accept the answer"

Answer (score 2):

You can only resize partitions to include adjacent free space. In your case there is none, because

- `sda1` is at the beginning of the drive and
- there's another partition `sda2` right behind it.

Since `sda2` is an empty extended partition, I recommend that you delete it, then resize `sda1`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have `/dev/sda2` "in the middle", and since the scheme you see in `gparted` is a physical representation of the partitions on the disk, extending `/dev/sda1` would actually mean overwhelming `/dev/sda2`'s space, which of course is not allowed. So you need to first remove `/dev/sda2` in order to extend `/dev/sda1`

Answer (score 0):

There is 510MB of sda2 extended partition in between. You have to get rid of that, only then you can resize sda1.

As far as I know there is  only one way to achieve this. You have to create the partition table once again